# Оптимальный способ для задания тени сверху UIView на Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, box-shadow

Подскажите оптимальный способ задания вот такой тени над UIView (только с одной стороны - сверху):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
testView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
testView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: -2.0)
testView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
testView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.08
testView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]